# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx, nodejs

Tags: express, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-504

Nodejs (express) server is hosted on Ubuntu 16.04.  Using nginx as reverse proxy many sub-domains are pointing to same sever.  I have integrated payment gateway which after successful transaction redirects to a  URL.  However after sometime nginx returns response of 504 Gateway Time-out.  At the same time if I try to access same api from postman I get success response.

As this redirect is caused by payment gateway service, in request header it shows

*Origin: https://secure.ccavenue.com*
*Referer: https://secure.ccavenue.com*

I am not sure how to bypass this through nginx.

Comment: Thats not Nginx problem, 504 Gateway Timeout mean your app is not return any to Nginx.

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  Rectified code at server end.